# Why does replacing long long with int increase performance?

Tags: c++, performance

Some tasks on Codeforces result in a "TLE" (Time Limit Exceeded) when using a `long long` for some variables, while changing them to `int` results in an "Accepted".

How does that issue affect the code? How do compilers deal with it? Why is the code faster when using `int`?

Comment: Could be running up against 64 bit arithmetic on a 32 bit system, but ignore time complexity here. O(1) means fantastic time complexity, but that O(1) could take 14.5 billion years. You can have a O(log(n)) taking longer than O(n) because of bad cache handling by the first algorithm. Should be faster doesn't mean is faster. Algorithm can be awesome, but the implementation can still suck or be impractical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends heavily on the platform. Here are two instances of where using a `long long` may slow down your code:

1. If the CPU is not 64 bit (assuming that `long long` is 64 bit and `int` is 32 bit) then there is more work involved in performing operations such as addition.
2. If you are working on a lot of data, changing from an `int` to a `long long` can have a large impact because the data is twice as large. Pulling data from disk or ram to the CPU cache is expensive, and if the datatype is twice as big, the CPU must request data more often.